# Map inside recycler view CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to inflate a map inside recycler view

I am successful in that but when I try to set `latlng` bounds in `onBindViewHolder`
using

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(latLng_source);
    builder.include(latLng_destination);
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 0;
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

i get the following error

```
     Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int)` which `int` of padding to specify the map's dimensions?